# Loading new data with AJAX if there are new data in Django model fields

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

View:

```
def user_messages(request):
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    user = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'read' in request.POST:
            un = request.POST.get('read')
            Messages.objects.filter(id=un).update(is_read=True)


        else:
            sender = request.user
            receiver_name = request.POST.get('msg_receiver')
            receiver = User.objects.get(username=receiver_name)
            msg_content = request.POST.get('msg_content')

            Messages.objects.create(sender=sender, receiver=receiver, msg_content=msg_content)

    inbox = Messages.objects.filter(receiver=user).order_by('-timestamp')
    outbox = Messages.objects.filter(sender=user).order_by('-timestamp')

    context = {'inbox': inbox, 'outbox': outbox, 'time_now': time_now}

    return render(request, 'accounts/messages.html', context)
```

Whenever there is a new message in inbox, I want AJAX to update the div with the new message

```
<div id="inbox">
            <h6>Inbox</h6>
            {% for message in inbox %}
                <ul>
                    <li title="{{ message.sender.username }}">
                        {{ message.sender.first_name }}: {{ message.msg_content }}
                        {% if message.is_read == False %}
                            <form action="{% url 'messages' %}" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <button value="{{ message.id }}" name="read">mark as read</button>
                            </form>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if message.is_read == True %}
                            <button onclick="reply()">Reply</button>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                    <small>-{{ message.timestamp }}</small>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I loop through the inbox and print out the messages. But whenever there is a new message, the user has to refresh the page see the changes.

I want Ajax to update only the div asynchronously. How I use Ajax to see if the inbox.count has increased and if increased, then add the new data to the list?

Comment: My recomendation: Use websockets and django channels.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `GET` in this view to return `Messages.objects.filter(is_read=False)` for each user. So your Ajax function needs to make a request to this route every x seconds.